# Re-posted faculty position. Worth waiting? (and two-body problem...)

Tags: job-search, faculty-application, two-body-problem

I applied for a faculty position at a state research (not so intensive) school in June. Since the position requires both a clinical degree and a research degree, their application pool is not likely to be large.

Then, in mid-August, I emailed a search committee chair to update my CV with a new publication, and the person said he would be in touch soon...  At first, I got optimistic when I read his reply, but decided not to think much about it.

In late August, they re-posted the position on their website...  It was the same posting, so my application materials were still there...  I thought I would get at least a phone interview opportunity but haven't heard from them since I sent my updated CV.  It's likely that they think I am not good enough for their position or do not meet their requirements...? Or internal candidate? or preferred candidate?

I really want to get this position...and I don't know what to do at this point.  My spouse is also in academia, and this might be my only chance to live with him...  Is there a chance that I hear from them this month or November?  Or should I just stop hoping and try to find jobs out of state...

Comment: If they had an internal or preferred candidate, then it seems unlikely that they'd re-post. Surely they'd keep applications open for the shortest possible time?

Answer (score 2):

> I really want to get this position...and I don't know what to do at this point.

There is not much you *can* do at this point. The search committee has your application materials, and will get back to you if the position is relevant.

> My spouse is also in academia, and this might be my only chance to live with him...

This might be in your favor. Did your spouse recently get hired? Could they try and negotiate for a spousal hire for you? It is possible that you may be able to negotiate a position for you if your spouse's faculty wants them to stay. It may not be the most ideal position for you, but it will be something. After all, it is more than reasonable that your spouse leaves if you aren't unable to get your career started at your current location. If they want to avoid that, they need to help you figure it out.

> Is there a chance that I hear from them this month or November? Or should I just stop hoping and try to find jobs out of state...

You might never hear from them, you might hear from them tomorrow. We can't answer that. However, you should most definitely keep looking for alternatives, and assume you have nothing from them until they send an offer letter for you to sign. If I were in your position I'd look for positions wherever I can. I would also explore how open my spouse is to relocating if need be.

Good luck!

Comment: I’ll add that in my opinion, while it isn’t good news that they reopened the call after your submission, it’s not an obvious sign you won’t get the job or that you’re not under consideration.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!  He has been hired for 2 years, so he cannot make a negotiation at this point. And, unfortunately, his institution doesn't have a department that fits me.  I started applying for other positions out of state... and hope that him and I live together one day...

Comment: I have been unemployed for almost 9 months since graduation and even gave up on two offers because the places were not close to where he was or he could not find position near where I received offers...  but being unemployed for 9 months exhusted me to the point that I am having a difficulty falling in a sleep every night...  Anyways, thank you for your comments!

Comment: @costt I think that your spouse may still have some options to negotiate, but only if you two are willing to relocate for your career. While the advice of random strangers on the internet doesn't count for much, I personally believe that the happiness of a couple is the minimum of the happiness of any one of them. If you are deeply unhappy where you two are, a relocation should be on the table.

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum you need to ask whether your application is still active. Don't assume that it is, though it may be. But reposting the position may mean a lot of things including the possibility that none of the current application pool is desirable and they want to start over.

If your application is no longer active, you may just need to submit it again.

There may be other reasons for the reposting, including a simple mistake or an administrative requirement. But if you don't ask, you may never know.

Comment: "If your application is no longer active, you may just need to submit it again."  Highly improbable.

Comment: @Buffy thank you for your comment.  When I log into their application system, the job posting link attached to my application is the one that has been re-posted.  That's how I guessed my application is still active with their re-posted posting.  Good suggestion.  I was just afraid that the search committee would feel bothered if I contact him again because I already contacted him to inquire about status once and then also to update him with my publication records.  So emailed him twice already...  But I guess I need to try one more time since there is nothing to lose for doing that.

Comment: @Anonymousp why do you think it is highly improbable